# No Ubuntu boot option after solo clean install and boot repair (HP Laptop)

Tags: boot, grub2, hp, menu

I initially tried to install Ubuntu for dual booting with Windows 10 on my HP laptop but the troubles of windows boot manager thwarting grub proved too much for me so I decided on a clean, lone install of Ubuntu. My problem now arises from it not appearing in the boot menu screen on startup now, only the usb drive that was used to install it (I get the options 'Try Ubuntu without installing', 'Install Ubuntu', 'OEM...', 'Disk Checks..').

I'm new to Ubuntu so don't know exactly how to be too helpful in this post. I tried the boot repair and generated this : http://paste2.org/8Im3x2UI .

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried removing the USB stick? It sounds like it's set in a higher boot priority than the HDD.